# Azure App service takes too much time to get result of EF Count()

Tags: azure, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my code:

```
public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> syslogger, SqliteContext sqliteContext)
{
    logger.LogInformation("start to get Data count");
    TotalCount = context.Data.Count();
    logger.LogInformation("end to get Data count");
}
```

and I get these log entries:

```
2023-09-11 02:45:44.614 +00:00 [INF] start to get Data count
2023-09-11 02:46:10.323 +00:00 [INF] end to get Data count
```

My database has about 1.4 million rows, stored in SQLite in the `App_Data` folder; the EF Core context took 26 seconds to get the count of the data.

My app is hosted in an Azure App Service with a Basic B1 Plan.

My app is using .NET 7.0 self container ASP.NET Core Razor Pages,
the code is inside the constructor of the `page.cshtml.cs`.

My local dev PC just take less than 200 ms.

I want to know: is the performance expected for the Basic B1 Plan?

Comment: Does it take long every time or only the first one? Also why are you using SQLite in general?

Comment: @GuruStron, every time. because SQLite is free to use.

Comment: And where the SQLite db is stored? As part of the app (i.e. is deployed with the code and is the part of running instance)?

Comment: @GuruStron, /wwwroot/AppData/db/mydbfile .

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service [Basic B1 Plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/app-service/linux/) has 1 Core of [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-b-series-burstable):

> B-series run on the 3rd Generation Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8370C (Ice Lake), the Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8272CL (Cascade Lake), the Intel® Xeon® 8171M 2.1 GHz (Skylake), the Intel® Xeon® E5-2673 v4 2.3 GHz (Broadwell), or the Intel® Xeon® E5-2673 v3 2.4 GHz (Haswell) processors.

Which I'm pretty sure is much less than available to your app on your machine.

And B1 has 1.75 Gbs of RAM.

1.4M of rows can take quite a lot of space. For example if one row is approximately 1kb, the data will take ~1.4 Gbs. The .NET app with runtime + libraries can easily take 50-200 Mbs, plus something is needed for the OS itself, meaning that you will be near the memory limit if the app, if you try to place everything into memory (thought not sure if SQLite will try to fit the whole dataset into memory, check the memory usage when running the app locally) which can lead to some kind of paging, so this in theory could be a huge factor too. Though as far as I can see default cache size is ~2 Mbs for SQLite and count in general should not require loading full data.

I would try to use at least B2 and compare the performance difference.

Comment: it is just Count, no reason to load everything into memory.

Comment: @MingTong that is mentioned in my answer.